# Can I create a role to write files to S3 bucket, valid for any user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform

I want to send someone keys that enable them to write files to an S3 bucket of my choice.  I created the bucket, and I want to create a ... "role", with associated keys, and set the bucket's permissions so the role can create files in it.  Can this be done?  How?

I am not very familiar with AWS as you can tell.  In the Google Cloud, I can do this by creating a "service account", downloading its .json key, and then giving the service account "Admin" access to the GCS bucket.  I can then send the .json key to whomever I want, or use it from any server -- the .json key is not specific to another "user".

In AWS, I haven't been able to do it.  It seems I have to know the user ID of the user to assume the role?  (which I don't know, I am trying to have a company upload data to my bucket and I don't know what users the company is using, etc).
But I am a beginner in AWS and I think I am just trying to do things the wrong way.  How can I do the equivalent of the above in Google Cloud in AWS?

Comment: a role can't have keys, what you need is a "User", which can either have an attached "Policy" or be part of a "Group" which has an attached "Policy". I find the best way to do all this is to describe it in YAML and deploy via CloudFormation - here's some docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-iam-user.html#cfn-iam-user-policies

Comment: Ok.  What's the equivalent of a "service account" then?  Is there an equivalent notion?  These are accounts that are not users, they are accounts with keys that can be used for programmatic access... is there this notion in AWS?

Comment: sorry, i hit return too quickly and have edited my above comment - you need a User which has keys for programmatic access

Comment: for example PolicyDocument: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html#aws-resource-iam-policy--examples

for available S3 actions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html

Comment: sorry, i had assumed based on your requirements that you want to give these keys to a human for ad-hoc use, but for machine access, yes, you would want to use a "Role" ... you grant access to a Role from an EC2 via its "InstanceProfile" ... but if you're off-AWS you need to rig up something like this (which i have never done) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/instances-on-premises-prerequisites.html

Comment: @Luca Who are these "users" and how many users are there? Are they trusted parties, or just random people who use your website? How will they use these keys — will they be putting them in an application (eg Cyberduck), or will they use a website or the AWS Console? Can you tell us more about your application and what users are doing? This can help us provide a more appropriate answer. Please edit your question to add these additional details rather than putting them in a comment.